# how to show images with time interval

Tags: android

I want to create a splash screen,i want 5 images to be displayed back to back at certain time interval,Tried following code but didn't worked shows last image directly after few seconds blank screen.

```
img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic3);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic4);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic5);
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: `shows last image directly after few seconds blank screen` because calling `Thread.sleep(10000);` on UI Thread. use [Hanlder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a new class called Handle which sets the image provided after 1 sec, and you call it the number of times you want.

```
public Void ImageWork {
public ImageWork(String vi){
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
       v.setImageResource(vi);
     }
  }, 1000);
}
}


final ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
new ImageWork("R.drawable.pic1");
new ImageWork("R.drawable.pic2");
new ImageWork("R.drawable.pic3");
new ImageWork("R.drawable.pic4");
new ImageWork("R.drawable.pic5");
```

You can also use **for** loop to increment the number(pic1,pic2...)